# Allure report on Jenkins producing NAN% and null report URL

Tags: javascript, jenkins, allure

Allure report on Jenkins producing NAN% and null report URL. I have a pipeline below and it is generating the report on the URL /null/. It was working fine before my added ${env.HOME} in my directories. But now it does not work

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        label {
            label ""
            customWorkspace "${env.HOME}/test"
        }
    }


  tools {nodejs "node"}

  stages {
        stage('Checkout App') {
            steps {
                dir("${env.HOME}/app") {
                echo "Building.."
                sh 'git pull'
                }
                // build shopfloor app
                dir("${env.HOME}/app") {
                sh "/${env.HOME}/test/App.sh"
                } 
            }
        }


    }

        post('Publish Report') {
          always {
            script {
              allure([
                includeProperties: false,
                jdk: '',
                properties: [],
                reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                results: [[path: 'target/allure_results']]
              ])
            }
          }
        }

}
```

It says allure report generated on:

```
allure-results does not exists
Report successfully generated to /Users/john/.jenkins/null/test/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a directory with `dir("${env.HOME}/app"){...}` inside the workspace. For that reason, allure didn't find the results, you could do something like this:

Check if the path is correct, but this will be an example:

```
results: [[path: '$WORKSPACE/${env.HOME}/app/target/allure_results']]
```

Comment: One more thing, how do i cleanup before running a new one, because it is showing old report

Comment: @Jason_Jenkins you have 2 options:
1. In your case the allure-results are inside target directory. If you execute `mvn clean` before executing any test, target will be deleted including everything inside like `allure-results` directory then when you run tests again you won't see old tests again.
2. You can clean your workspace as first step in your pipeline `cleanWs()`, then you will have an empty `allure-results` directory.